# Error: Program type already present: org.kobjects.base64.Base64 while generating signed APK

Tags: android, android-studio

java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete 
com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Program type already present: org.kobjects.base64.Base64

everything  whatever  on stackoverflow

java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete 
com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Program type already present: org.kobjects.base64.Base64

signed  APK

Answer (score 0):

What this error means is that the type `org.kobjects.base64.Base64` is present more than once in the input. This is typically caused by more than one of the dependencies (including their transitive dependencies) you have added having this type.

Try to go through the dependencies to figure out where this type is included.

You can use the following commands to display the transitive dependencies:

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
./gradlew app:androidDependencies
```